# Matlab program for Rayleigh wave

Tags: matlab, wave-equation

Respected all members, can any one provide me Matlab program for Rayleigh wave propagation in any medium. Please mention the paper also  containing that program

Comment: What you are asking for is a huge amount of work and demonstrates that you did not attempt do this on your own.

Comment: I am working on Rayleigh wave. With the help of that program I can try to make new program in required medium .

Comment: Yes, I get that this is an important problem to you.  However, you are asking someone to do your work for you for free, with appropriately cited research, thorough testing, and basically turn-key ready matlab code.  That is not a reasonable request, especially with poor specifications like you've given.  What are the inputs?  Where do you want your code to start?  What kinds of outputs do you want?  What format?  Is it a function?  A script?  A toolbox?  How much functionality do you want?...